# On sup over boundaries of Sobolev functions

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

In [Gilbarg-Trudinger](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540411604)'s section on the maximum principle for weak solutions, the sup of a boundary of a Sobolev function defined as follows:

> Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For $u, v \in H^1(\Omega)$, $u \leq v$ on $\partial \Omega $ if $(u-v)^+ \in H^1_0 (\Omega)$. Define
> $$\sup_{\partial \Omega} u = \inf \; \{ k \in \mathbb{R} \; | \; u \leq k \text{ on } \partial \Omega \}, \quad u \in H^1(\Omega).$$

Here, of course, $H^1(\Omega) = W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ and $H^1_0(\Omega) = W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$.

My simple question is whether the following inequalities are valid.

> Let $u, v \in H^1(\Omega)$.
>
> 1. $\sup_{\partial \Omega} (u+v) \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega} u + \sup_{\partial \Omega} v.$
> 2. For $k \in \mathbb R$ with $\sup_{\partial \Omega} u \leq k$, $u \leq k$ on $\partial \Omega$.
> 3. If $u \leq v$ on $\partial \Omega$, then $\sup_{\partial \Omega} u \leq \sup_{\partial \Omega} v.$

I tried to prove these inequalities by the definition, but it does not seem straightforward. However, if we assume that the domain is at least Lipschitz, then we can use the trace operator. Considering [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079409/the-essential-sup-over-the-boundary-vs-the-trace-of-a-sobolev-function) post on Math.SE, I can produce a quite straightforward proof for these inequalities since the sup over the boundary is the usual essential sup over the boundary.

I initially guessed that the inequalities can be showed even if we do not require any regularity on the boundary, but now I am not sure. Is there any proof without using the trace operator?

Thanks!

P.S I posted the same question on Math.SE. ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3799149/on-the-boundary-sup-of-sobolev-functions))

Comment: Too soon, too soon...

Comment: Yes, they are true without any assumption on $\Omega$ and follow from the ideal properties of $H^1$. First one shows that for $u, v \in H^1$, then $|u|, u^+, u\wedge v \in H^1$ and these maps (with $v$ fixed) are continuous from $H^1$ into itself. Then one shows that $0 \le u \le v$ with $v \in H^1_0$ yields $u \in H^1_0$ (if $\phi_n \to v$ then $\phi_n \wedge u \to v\wedge u=u$ and $\phi_n \wedge u$ has compact support).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thanks for the comment. Actually, I thought that it boils down to the fact that $0 \leq u \leq v$ with $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ implies $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ for $u, v \in H^1 (\Omega)$. Is this a special property of $H^1$?

Comment: It holds in $W^{1,p}_0$ and the proof is sketched in my previous comment.

Comment: I was wondering if this "ordering" $u\le v$ on $\partial\Omega$ is transitive?